# How can I recognize Japanese Characters using OpenCV, C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr

I have a program that extracts Japanese Characters from Manga pages and I want to know what characters they are using character recognition.

I have been playing with Template Matching and trying to implement a KNearest from scratch

How can I recognize the extracted characters?

I can't find any good example on C++ about KNearest. I also would want to avoid Tesseract if possible.

I have tried template matching on the character detection image and it detected properly but I need it to detect the extracted character. It can't detect it accurately while playing with the code from http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html

Example of Character Detection:

[image: Example of Character Detection]

Example of Extracted Characters:

[image: Example of Extracted Character][image]

Example of a template or a training data:

[image][image]

Comment: TBH "I have 2 days" isn't contributing to the question. If anything, it signals that you didn't put much work in it. I don't think it's enough time. OCR is a non-trivial problem even with 26 Latin characters.

Comment: @MSalters It really isn't enough time, that's why I'm asking here since I'm desperate. I've been trying this for 2 months and nothing good came out of it

Comment: Wll, I'not surprised if you stuck with the simple template matching from the OpenCV example. Can't explain the whole theory here but in short: your detection methods should be robust against irrelevant transformations. For instance, small rotation in handwriting are irrelevant. When template matching, that probably means you should not just slide but also wiggle.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to get much further with Template Matching as its quite susceptible to variations. OpenCV does provide implementations of KNN and several other ML techniques ([link](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.9/modules/ml/doc/k_nearest_neighbors.html)) that might offer more robust solutions.